# Parsing an FQL result

Tags: ios, objective-c, parsing, facebook-fql

I'm using FQL to get the names of the nearest 5 places like so:

```
- (void)facebookPlaces {

    NSString *query = @"SELECT name FROM place WHERE distance(latitude, longitude, \"39.750655\", \"-104.999127\") < 500 ORDER BY distance(latitude, longitude, \"23.750655\", \"-180.999127\") limit 5";

    // Set up the query parameter
    NSDictionary *queryParam = @{ @"q": query };
    // Make the API request that uses FQL
    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/fql"
                                 parameters:queryParam
                                 HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                          completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                              id result,
                                              NSError *error) {
                              if (error) {
                                  NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                              } else {
                                  NSLog(@"Result: %@", result);
                                  // Store the result in an NSData object
                                  NSData *nameData = [result data];
                                  NSLog(@"Test data reads: %@", nameData);

                              }
                          }];
```

The result is neatly returned like this:

```
Result: {
    data =     (
                {
            name = "T|aco";
        },
                {
            name = "ChoLon Bistro";
        },
                {
            name = "Illegal Pete's Lodo";
        }, etc...
```

I stored the data in an NSData object and it reads the exact same way. I would like to parse the result in a way that I can get all of the names in a simple way, and print them to the log. The only way that I could think of was manually parsing the NSData or the result, but I have no idea how to make it only take the stuff in the quotes next to `name =`. I'm very new to FQL and objective-c, does anyone know how I can do this?

When I researched this, I saw an awesome JSON example that took everything next to `name =` and stored it in an array. Although it was meant for android and I couldn't figure out how to make it work in iOS. That is ideally what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is being parsed as a JSON object into an `NSDictionary`.  You can tell because the result object starts with `{}`.  Inside the `data` key you see an array (denoted by `()`).

So to get an array of names you can do this:

```
NSMutableArray *names = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSDictionary *item in result[@"data"]) {
    [names addObject:item[@"name"]];
}
```

Is this what you're after?